# How to validate forms

Tags: php

I am new in PHP programming and I am creating my first registration and login form. I did everything but there is one problem: How I must sort the code. I tried in lots of ways but it is messed up.

```
if (filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)) {

    if (preg_match('/\s/', $name)) {
        $errorName = "Names doesn't contain whitespaces";
        $mainError = true;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM register WHERE name='$name'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $errorName = 'This name is already registered';
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if (mb_strlen($name) > 0 AND mb_strlen($name) < 3) {
        $errorName = 'Name too short';
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if (mb_strlen($name) > 15) {
        $errorName = 'Name too long';
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if ($name == '') {
        $errorName = 'This field is REQUIRED';
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errorEmail = "Invalid email";
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if (preg_match('/\s/', $pass1)) {
        $errorName = "Password mustn't contain whitespaces";
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if (mb_strlen($pass1) > 0 AND mb_strlen($pass1) < 6) {
        $errorPass1 = 'Password too short';
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if (mb_strlen($pass1) > 20) {
        $errorPass1 = 'Password too long';
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if ($pass1 == '') {
        $errorPass1 = 'This field is REQUIRED';
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if ($pass1 != $pass2) {
        $errorPass2 = "Passwords don't match";
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if ($pass2 == '') {
        $errorPass2 = 'This field is REQUIRED';
        $mainError = true;
    }

    if (!$mainError) {
        $feedback = 'You registered successfully!';
    }


}
```

I want to know what must be first

Comment: What do you mean how to sort the code? The order of the if's doesn't really matter in this case, as long as they're all there. What is the problem you're having with this code?

Comment: Look at the password field. When I type my name or email it says This field is reaquired again : http://imgur.com/NxlidE3

Comment: I would write a separate function, but @Oldskool is right: order does not matter if you just need to check for all these conditions. You can however optimise by returning on fail, because now it checks everything even if it failed before.

Comment: What do you mean by separate function?

Comment: a function that has this code in the body with a name like `validate_form()` that returns `true` or `false`

Comment: moreover, I would add frontend validation in JS, now the check is done by server which is resource consuming and slower. You can use good existing libraries like http://parsleyjs.org/